# meteor Session.setDefault converts object to array?

Tags: meteor

Dead simple code in a file in `client/lib` folder of my MeteorJS application:

```
Session.setDefault("location", {lon: -74.00, lat: 40.71}); // New York

console.log(Session.get("location"));
```

Console output:

```
[-74, 40.71]
```

I can easily work around this. But I'm very curious why this is happening?

Comment: `Session.get` should return an object. My guess is it's just being set somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You're right. I created a new project and tested the same code and got back an object. I removed the `.meteor/local/build` folder and restarted meteor and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
locationObj = new Object();
locationObj.lon = -74.00;
locationObj.lat = 40.71;
Session.setDefault("location", locationObj);
```

I think it is taking just the values, instead of recognizing lat and lon as fields.

Please excuse the "Samel K" account answering, that was my friends account, looks like he was trying to trick me into getting him repuation.